# Laravel Eloquent HasManyThrough - Product, Category, Colours

Tags: laravel, eloquent, has-many-through

I need to select all products in a category with certain colors, this to have in the category view (with colors specified by a form), all the products of that category, but only of the selected colors.

i have try this... but I know I'm wrong! I haven't understand well the hasManyThrough...

in Prodotto model:

```
 public function categoria() // il nome del metodo è il metodo della relazione
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Categoria::class,
            'id','categoria_id'
        );

    }


 public function colori()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Colore::class , 'prodotto_colore')->withTimestamps();
}
```

in Colore model:

```
public function prodottiCategoriaColore()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Prodotto::class, Categoria::class);
}
```

in Categoria model:

```
public function prodotti() // il nome del metodo è il metodo della relazione
{
    return $this->hasMany(Prodotto::class,
        'categoria_id','id'
    );
}
```

in CategoriaController:

```
private function colore($categoriaId , $coloreId)
    {
        $categoria_qb = Categoria::query()
            ->where('id', '=', $categoriaId)->with('prodotti');

        $prodottiColore_qb = $categoria_qb->where('colore_id' , $coloreId)->with('prodottiCategoriaColore');

        $prodotti = $prodottiColore_qb->first();

        return view('frontend.categoria', ['prodotti' => $prodotti]);

    }
```

in DB i have a table for prodotti, one for colori, one for category and a pivot prodotto_colore (product ID - colour ID)

Comment: So a category has many products and a product has many colours, is that right?

Comment: yes... correct!